# How can I use a desktop like a laptop

Tags: laptop, desktop-computer

I am not looking for a remote control application.

I need a new computer. Typically I buy desktop-replacement laptops and use them in the exact same location (my couch).

I would like to save $ and gain upgradability by using a desktop, but still be able to use it from my couch.

Is there any sort of "stub" laptop with just a keyboard and screen that I can (wirelessly/wired) connect to a tower sitting next to the couch?

How about some sort of "lap stand" for the monitor?, as trying to balance a normal monitor on my lap seems like a quick path to failure.

Comment: Do you really need to use this stuff on your lap, or would a rolling tray work well enough?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking here, and there's really no way to give a "factual answer" (refer to [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)). Just letting you know as this question is being voted to close.

Comment: How is this not a factual question? Either there is a way to accomplish what I am asking (using some class of hardware X) or there isn't. None of the FAQ conditions apply to this question...

Comment: This is such an unusual request that you would probably spend more money on a custom-engineered solution than you would spend just buying a desktop replacement laptop. But if you absolutely insist, you may be able to build something like a "stub laptop" using Intel WiDi (wireless display) and a bluetooth keyboard. Not sure what you'd do about a power solution; some kind of battery?

Comment: Anyway, I agree with the vote to close, because this question is basically a shopping / makers question. Of *course* it is "possible"; if you had a team of 20 engineers with experience designing laptops, you could probably churn out a professional product in a couple months. Nothing about physics or hardware makes it impossible. But if you want to know more than possible, and want to know if any solutions actually exist, it's a shopping question. So there are two horns: either it's a vacuous "of course it's possible" question, or it's shopping. Do you see why it's off topic now?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its called a wireless keyboard/mouse and a long cable for your screen :)

Or, you could buy a cheap netbook and use VNC to export the desktop's screen to the netbook.

Comment: VNC won't work, gaming is one of my primary purposes. I obviously thougt of this solution already, my issue is is there any way to "mount" the LCD so that it will work well on a lap?

Comment: @JasonCoyne You could mount it on a wall with a VESA mounting arm you can move around. These can be expensive though.